# MIT 1995 Puzzle Hunt: Unsolved "Connecticut Suite" Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, unsolved-mysteries

Many of the solutions to the [1995 MIT Puzzle Hunt](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/1995/mysteryhunt1995.pdf) have been lost.  Several groups have been able to solve most of them, but **#23 Connecticut Suite** remains elusive.

Here is a reproduction of the puzzle.  The leadup is probably irrelevant, but I've included it anyways.  All the puzzles that year were Clue-themed.

> "Oriental Suite is down that corridor and the Vermont Bedroom is around the corner there, but this is Phillip's favorite by far.  I rather like it myself," Peacock said with a glint in her eye.
>
> "Oh really?  What about it tickles your fancy?" Plum said, edging closer to her.
>
> "The facilities are so lavish. The mood is so romantic. The air is charged with a certain fire. It tends to draw people together," Peacock said in a voice so sultry it could melt the coal buttons off a snowman. "Let me show you just what I mean."
>
> "Oooh, baby," Plum exhaled as he and Peacock collapsed on the bed. The two of them were as tangled as a slinky in a dishwasher, and never even notice[sic] the puzzle taped to the nightstand.
>
> 1. WALKER  TRAVERSE  HERRING  LAZARUS
> 2. WISDOM  FOLLOWS  KUBRICK  STAMMER
> 3. WALL  MAXIM  COURT  PEARL
> 4. FLOYD  CROOKS  EINSTEIN  FIZZ  LOW
> 5. NORTH  CREW  FILLMORE  DEMOS
> 6. HUSSEIN  DING  CHRIST
> 7. SHARON  STONER  BUTTERS  TYSON  STALKER
> 8. BREWER  CHAMPAGNE  STRANGE  RAN

The solution is

> VIVACITY

but I don't know how it's derived.

The winning team solved it within the few days of the hunt, so the solution shouldn't be impossibly difficult.

Comment: Maybe this is worthy of the [tag:unsolved-mysteries] tag.

Comment: The number of sentences and the the number of letters in the solution is the same-8.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay: Yep!  The appearance of "Floyd+Wall" and "Sharon+Stone(r)" is also suspicious.  Many of the words are also part of a common two-word phrase (eg. "red herring", "Millard Fillmore", "wisdom teeth"), but replacing each word with its pair doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Peacock is a *male* variety...so it should have been _peahen_,  I suppose! ;-)

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay: Yes, but Mrs Peacock and Professor Plum are suspects in the game Clue or Cluedo.

Comment: Are we sure that the answer is correct?

Comment: @jsm: The answer was needed to solve the metapuzzle, so it's almost certainly correct

Comment: Would it be possible we need to pair each word with a complement? like Einstein -> Albert, Hussein -> Saddam, Tyson -> Mike, North -> South, Kubrick -> Stanley, Wisdom -> knowledge, ding -> dong ...

Comment: Although most of the preamble looks irrelevant, there are strong hints that we looking at things that are tangled together. Also, there is only one V in the puzzle words, but two Vs in the answer so we'll need a way to introduce extra letters.

Comment: I’m thinking something along the lines of the letters being spelled out by lines joining multiple points of interest. For example, if the clues really do relate to a monopoly board, you could spell out a V by going from Jail, to Short Line, to Free Parking. Similarly, it might be possible to draw lines over the text clues to join similar words.

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest, from the inclusion of Oriental, Connecticut and Vermont, that Monopoly will be involved somehow. Those are three of the properties in the light blue group on the US board.

[Wiki article on Monopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game))

How that ties to the words I'm not sure, but we might need one group of monopoly properties per sentence. Each group also seems to contain at least one last name of a person. Stanley Kubrick, Albert Einstein, Ariel Sharon?, Sadam Hussein, Mike Tyson? There might be others. The colors might be also hinted at in each set, tying each to a property.

Comment: Yep, that's been noticed before too!  But simply noticing that does not provide a solution, so I think this would have been better as a comment...

Comment: Perhaps this should be a "Community Chest Wiki"? `:)` (I'm not sure whether this should be a comment or a partial answer, but the information is very useful for those not familiar with the US Monopoly board.)

Comment: You say it’s been noticed before, but where? If this has been discussed elsewhere, can we have a link? No benefit to duplication of effort.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought it might get a little more visibility. Mentioning what's been tried or known would be very useful though.